# select date from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this value of date in database: `01-03-12 13:25:50`. How I can select this date in this format: DD.MM.YYYY .  I try to round it: `ROUND(to_date(datum_zalozeni, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DAY')` but format is still same...

Comment: What is the type of your date in the database? Your query seems to try to convert a string to a date, not the other way around which the question implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR(datum_zalozeni, 'DD.MM.YYYY')`

Official docs for `TO_CHAR`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

Formats for dates: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#sthref416

Answer (score 0):

If it is a DATE then you can do this:

```
select to_char( mycol, 'DD.MM.YYYY') from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_char(to_date(datum_zalozeni, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select to_char(datum_zalozeni, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```